# telerik grid validation ORM and view model classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm having problems getting validation in my Telerik grid. I have built viewmodels and put data annotations in them but I can't use them. With Telerik grid I can only use ORM classes to select data.

How do I pass data through viewmodel classes from ORM classes so I can have validation?

I use Telerik ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Im posting my solution in case somebody else has the same or similar problem

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {//getting data from database
        var narucitelji= _repository.GetNarucitelji() ;
        Liste liste=new Liste();     //put data from ORM class to ViewModel
        foreach (var item in narucitelji)
        {
            Narucitelj_mod nar=new Narucitelj_mod();
            nar.ID_narucitelja=item.ID_narucitelja;
            nar.Ime_narucitelja=item.Ime_narucitelja;
            nar.Prezime_narucitelja=item.Prezime_narucitelja;
            nar.Adresa_narucitelja=item.Adresa_narucitelja;
            liste.NarList.Add(nar);
        }
   //return list 
        return View(liste.NarList);
    }
```

In foreach loop I get the data from ORM class to ViewModel class. Liste is a class where I have a list in which I put the data I which is in the ViewModel. In the end you send the list to the view.
Make sure to reference the List and the View to your ViewModel

Comment: one piece of observation ... you do not need to do a foreach loop i think. You can use LINQ and write a LINQ query to create the ViewModel class something like this: from item in repository.GetNarucitelji() select new Narucitelj_mod() { prop1 = item.prop1 .... }. this elimiated your for each loop...